# Lucene indexCommit serializable?

Tags: serialization, lucene, commit

IndexCommit does not inherit java.io.Serialiable - does that mean one cannot persist it to another data store? So what I want is to save a list of writing history, i.e., list of commit points, so that even if I bounce my lucene based process, I can still travel back to a particular commit point before the bounce. Is that possible in Lucene?

Comment: Have you seen [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5897784/lucene-index-backup)? Is this good enough for what you need?

Comment: @mindas I understand what you suggest, but what I need is different. I need to do a two-phase commit between Lucene and another data store. When user's search request comes in, the other data store picks it up first, goes to the commit point of Lucene that is synchronized with itself, and then fulfills the user's request. Now since the writing is quite often, I cannot save each and every snapshots to a separate backup directory, which is just unfeasible.

Comment: What you need sounds really complicated, and I'm not sure if I understand it fully. Anyway, Lucene does support two phase commit (`IW.prepareCommit()` & `IW.commit()`). Hope this helps.